# EF 4.x generated entity classes (POCO) and Map files

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have an MVC 4 app that I am working on and using the code first implementation except I cheated a bit and created my database first then generated my entity classes (poco) from my database using the EF power tools (reverse engineer). I guess you can say I did database first method but I have no edmx file just the context class and my entity classes (poco)

I have a few projects in the works using MVC and EF with pocos but just the one project I used the tool to generate my pocos from the database.

My question is about the mapping files that get created when I generate my pocos using the tool. What is the purpose of these Map files? I figured the map files are needed when generating the db from the model like with the true code first method, in my case where I am using a tool to generate my model from the database do the map files have any influence on how my app uses the entity classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping files are to [fluent files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295844%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) help Code First generate the database from your model, as well as help EF create the proper relationships.

- They can [map properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591617) - things like setting a primary key, max length, data type.
- They can also [map relationships](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591620) - set things like foreign keys, and defining relationships that don't follow standard CF naming conventions.

Even though you're not generating your database from the app, CF will use this system to ensure that the database it's pointing to is compatible with your model, and in the case of foreign keys and things setup related properties.  For example, if you wanted to name a FK something other than `NavigationPropertyId`, you would need fluent to tell the engine what property to set in the database.